# Use the elements of the list in a format function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I want to do something like:

```
(setf list '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
(format t "~A some text here ~A ~A ~A more text here ~A ~A" list)
```

And have the output be

> 1 some text here 2 3 4 more text here 5 6

How can I do this without calling (nth 1 list) (nth 2 list) etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
(apply #'format t "~A some text here ~A ~A ~A more text here ~A ~A" list)
```

Answer (score 11):

```
(format t "~{~A some text here ~A ~A ~A more text here ~A ~A~}" list)
```